# Startup Disk Creator fails to erase disk

Tags: dbus, startup-disk-creator

Before extracting an ISO image onto a USB device using [Startup Disk Creator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/usb-creator-gtk/), when I try to erase the USB device using the same software, I always get the following error:

[image: Startup disk creator error]

I have tried to erase various USB devices without success, so I believe this is not a device-specific problem.
I see that [a bug on this has been filed on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/924257), though an alternative/solution/word-around has not been suggested.

Is there a way to solve this error, without using other softwares to erase disk?

**System specifications:**

- Ubuntu 12.10
- Startup Disk Creator 0.2.4

Answer (score 5):

Try this.  Insert your USB flash drive, and just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
dmesg | tail
```

[image]

The `sdb` is your USB drive, yous might be different

Unmount your USB drive using the following command:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdx
```

Format the drive using the following command: (this would format it as FAT32)

```
sudo mkdosfs -F 32 -n 'Label' -I /dev/sdx
```

make sure that you replace the `x` with your device id.

Comment: I would appreciate a solution to this problem, not an alternative :) Though this should work.

Comment: OK, I can respect that.  Try this on on of the USB drives `sudo fsck -a`.

Comment: The device I am working on is a FAT device, the output of `dosfsck` is here: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6120192/, though the error remains.

Comment: OK.  Try formatting as FAT 32, and then try Startup Disk Creator again.

Comment: The error remains the same, @Mitch!

Comment: Try what I've included in my answer, just to see.

Comment: The same error in 14.04. This solution does not work.

Comment: `sudo systemctl stop udisks2`, then `umount`, then `mkdosfs` -- this worked for me. Some fancy `udisksd` kept re-mounting the drive instantly after I unmounted it manually.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

1. If you have Startup Disk Creator, Disk Utility, or GParted open, close them
2. Safely remove your USB flash drive and reinsert it
3. If it isn't already installed, install GParted through the Software Center or:

   ```
   sudo apt-get -y install gparted
   ```
4. Open GParted (in Xubuntu/Xfce it's in Settings) and select the USB drive from the dropdown near the top right
5. If there are any partitions on the drive, right-click them → *Unmount*
6. *Device* → *Create Partition Table* → *Select new partition table type* → *msdos* → *Apply*
7. *Partition* → *New* → *File system* → *fat32* → *Add*
8. Click the green check icon near the top to apply the changes → *Apply*
9. When it's done, close GParted, open Startup Disk Creator, and proceed as usual